# Problema al guardar imagen obtenida de intent en SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, picasso

el problema que tengo es que no logro pasar una imagen obtenida a través de un intent con el método Picasso a SharedPreferences, es decir, desde ActivityA mando una imagen a ActivityB mediante el método Picasso y al recibirla en ActivityB quiero guardarla en SharedPreferences. He probado de todo y no consigo que se guarde. Las imágenes en ActivityA las recupero desde Firebase Storage en forma de url y por eso uso el método Picasso y al recuperarla en ActivityB también la recupero con Picasso, pero no sé como pasar esa imagen obtenida de Picasso a SharedPreferences, algo me estoy dejando atrás. Dejo el código aquí abajo por si alguien puede echarme una mano. Un saludo y gracias!

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MiCuentaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    ImageView portada;
    Button botonDevolver;
    TextView tituloCuenta, editorialCuenta, autorCuenta, paginasCuenta, IsbnCuenta, resumenCuenta;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 0;
    private ImageView mImage;
    private Uri mImageUri, portadaUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mi_cuenta);

        tituloCuenta = findViewById(R.id.tvTituloCuenta);
        editorialCuenta = findViewById(R.id.tvEditorialCuenta);
        autorCuenta = findViewById(R.id.tvAutorCuenta);
        paginasCuenta = findViewById(R.id.tvPaginasCuenta);
        IsbnCuenta = findViewById(R.id.tvISBNCuenta);
        resumenCuenta = findViewById(R.id.tvResumenCuenta);
        portada = findViewById(R.id.ivImagenDetallesCuenta);
        botonDevolver = findViewById(R.id.btnDevolverLibro);
        mImage = findViewById(R.id.ivUsuario);
        TextView nombreUsuario = findViewById(R.id.tvNombreUsuario);
        nombreUsuario.setText(email);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String mImageUri = preferences.getString("image", null);
        String portadaUri = preferences.getString("portada", null);
        tituloCuenta.setText(preferences.getString("titulo", null));
        editorialCuenta.setText(preferences.getString("editorial", null));
        autorCuenta.setText(preferences.getString("autor", null));
        paginasCuenta.setText(preferences.getString("paginas", null));
        IsbnCuenta.setText(preferences.getString("isbn", null));
        resumenCuenta.setText(preferences.getString("resumen", null));

        if(tituloCuenta.getText()!="") {

            Toast.makeText(MiCuentaActivity.this, "Si quieres alquilar otro libro, debes devolver el que tienes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{

            Intent intent=getIntent();
            final Bundle b=intent.getExtras();

            if (b != null) {
                Picasso.with(MiCuentaActivity.this).load((b.getString("IMG"))).into(portada);
                tituloCuenta.setText(b.getString("TIT"));
                editorialCuenta.setText("Editorial: "+b.getString("EDI"));
                autorCuenta.setText("Autor: "+b.getString("AUT"));
                paginasCuenta.setText("Páginas: "+(Integer.toString(b.getInt("PAG"))));
                IsbnCuenta.setText("ISBN: "+(Long.toString(b.getLong("ISB"))));
                resumenCuenta.setText(b.getString("DET"));
                SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("portada", String.valueOf(portada));
                editor.putString("titulo", tituloCuenta.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("editorial", editorialCuenta.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("autor", autorCuenta.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("paginas", paginasCuenta.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("isbn", IsbnCuenta.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("resumen", resumenCuenta.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
            }
        }

        updateUI();

        if (mImageUri != null) {
            mImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mImageUri));
        } else {
            mImage.setImageResource(0);
        }

        mImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageSelect();
            }
        });

        botonDevolver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                limpiarPrefs();
            }
        });
    }

    public void imageSelect() {
        permissionsCheck();
        Intent intent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        }
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona una foto"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    public void permissionsCheck() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    mImageUri=data.getData();
                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(mImageUri));
                    editor.commit();
                    mImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
                    mImage.invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(){
        if(tituloCuenta.getText()=="") {
            findViewById(R.id.tvTituloCuenta).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvEditorialCuenta).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvAutorCuenta).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvPaginasCuenta).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvISBNCuenta).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvResumenCuenta).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.btnDevolverLibro).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvNoHayDatos).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            findViewById(R.id.tvTituloCuenta).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvEditorialCuenta).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvAutorCuenta).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvPaginasCuenta).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvISBNCuenta).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvResumenCuenta).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.btnDevolverLibro).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.tvNoHayDatos).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void limpiarPrefs(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MiCuentaActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Renbooks")
                .setMessage("¿De verdad quieres devolver el libro?")
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.stringYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        portada.setImageResource(0);
                        tituloCuenta.setText("");
                        editorialCuenta.setText("");
                        autorCuenta.setText("");
                        paginasCuenta.setText("");
                        IsbnCuenta.setText("");
                        resumenCuenta.setText("");

                        SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MiCuentaActivity.this);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
                        editor.remove("titulo");
                        editor.remove("editorial");
                        editor.remove("autor");
                        editor.remove("paginas");
                        editor.remove("isbn");
                        editor.remove("resumen");
                        editor.commit();
                        updateUI();
                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton(R.string.stringNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                    }).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente obtén el valor y guardalo en preferencias:

```
if (b != null) {
            Picasso.with(MiCuentaActivity.this).load((b.getString("IMG"))).into(portada);
            ... 
            ....
            editor.putString("imgUrl", b.getString("IMG"));
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
```

Para obtener la url usa la misma key que seria "imgUrl" y puedes verificar si existe para agregala a tu ImageView:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 String imageUrl = preferences.getString("imgUrl", null);

 portada = findViewById(R.id.ivImagenDetallesCuenta);
 if(imageUrl != null){
    Picasso.with(MiCuentaActivity.this).load(imageUrl)).into(portada); 
 }
```

Comment: Buenas Jorge, siempre se agradece tu ayuda ^^ , acabo de probarlo pero al insertar el Picasso que va después del if me tira error, me dice que cree el método into, y claro sin el into no me incorpora la portada como imagen

Comment: Es un poco raro , de hecho si te refieres a esta linea: Picasso.with(MiCuentaActivity.this).load((b.getString("IMG"))).into(portada); esta no cambio :|

Comment: Si es justo esa línea, me da error en .into y me dice que cree el método en esa activity. Sabes por que puede ser?